# Replaced Idle Air Control Vavle (IACV) and Still Stalling

Tags: ford, stall, iac-valve

**2004 Ford Taurus

SES, DOHC 24V**

Car stalls at stop lights ~once every 3 days.

Throttle body cleaned out ($150) - no difference.

Replaced IACV with Motor Craft OEM ($80). No stalling for 5 days but then back to original behavior - no difference now.

The work around is placing the car neutral at all stop lights, then doesn't stall.

- What is the next item to check?
- What other components are involved for this and how can each be tested/diagnosed?
- Reasons ***not*** to put back the old IACV (to save some money)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you reset idle strategies after cleaning the throttle body?

Comment: Do you have access to at least OBD2 live data?  I think it may be beneficial to see fuel trims, o2 voltages, maf, map, load%, and coolant temp at idle and cruise.  As far as putting the old iac valve back on to save money, any parts distributor I know of doesn't return electrical if installed.

Comment: @moab: I don't think the mechanic did that...just unplug the battery?

Comment: @milison: I don't but can get one...please put as answer and as to what a bad value for each one would be and what component it relates to. (FYI Amazon returned, told them I tried it...different business model than the old shop).

Comment: Are there no codes stored now or in the recent past?

Comment: There are many good articles that describe overall obd2 data interpretation, and as far as known good values, they might be found at https://www.pidfusion.net/datalogs/

Comment: @Milison: I assume the mechanic didn't find anything or he would have told me...

Comment: @P.S. there is more to it than that.